# Array indices as v-model in Vue template

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am looping through one array using `v-for` to show inputs for each item. How can I use another array as the v-model for those inputs?
Here's a codepen illustrating my problem. https://codepen.io/jkohlin/pen/XWMMLbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the new array items that you create in `this.prediction` by direct assignment are not reactive. This is why Vue template is not updated with the new values. To make a new property reactive you should use the global `Vue.set()` or `this.$set()` instance method.

```
  mounted() {
    this.dbSavedPredictions.forEach((prediction, i) => {
      this.$set(this.predictions, i, prediction);
    });
  },
```

You can read more about Vue reactivity and how to avoid such problems here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html